# setter and getter result in nil value in FactoryGirl with Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, getter-setter

In our invoice model, there are two columns - `customer_id` and `customer_name`. In order to use auto-complete (JQuery), a setter and getter for `customer_name` were added to invoice model:

```
  def customer_name
    customer.try(:name)
  end

  def customer_name=(name)
    self.customer = Customer.find_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
```

In invoice model, there is:

```
  belongs_to :customer
```

However after that, `customer_id` and `customer_name` are always `nil` by `FactoryGirl.build(:invoice)`. If the getter and setter were removed from the invoice model, then the FactoryGirl assigns the right value to `customer_id` and `customer_name`. Here is the FactoryGirl:

```
 factory :invoice do 
.....
    customer_id             2
    customer_name           'a customer name'
...

  end
```

Why does the getter and setter of `customer_name` result in `nil` in FactoryGirl?

Comment: This seems like a strange way to do things. How do you know for sure that a customer exists with id "2" when you create an invoice using the factory?

Comment: 2 is just a dummy value.

Comment: I really don't understand the logic of your models.

Comment: Those setter and getter were added for jquery autocomplete. There were no getter and setter before autocomplete was introduced. Logically there is not need for the getter and setter. They are here just for jquery autocomplete

Comment: But what do you mean when you say that FactoryGirl assigns the right value to `customer_id` and `customer_name` if the getter and setter are removed? How can it set anything if there are no setters?

Comment: FactoryGirl is used to prepare data for rspec and it can only assign nil to customer_id and customer_name if getter and setter are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FactoryGirl.build(:invoice)` doesn't actually save the newly instantiated object. You may need to use FactoryGirl's built-in callbacks to get this rollin.

*NOT TESTED*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer do
    name "A customer"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    name "An invoice"
    after_build do |invoice|
      invoice.customer = FactoryGirl.build(:customer)
    end
  end
end
```

Some resources...

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl

http://icelab.com.au/articles/factorygirl-and-has-many-associations/

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: No luck. Still nil for customer_id and customer_name. Here is the code:     after(:build) do |invoice|
      invoice.customer = FactoryGirl.build(:customer)
    end

Comment: Do you know why the FactoryGirl could not assign the value to customer_id and customer_name? Without the getter and setter, it can.

Comment: are `customer_id` and `customer_name` mapped to database columns in the invoice table?

Comment: Yes, customer_id and customer_name are two columns in invoices table.

Answer (score 0):

What we did was to add a field customer_name_autocomplete for jquery autocomplete, instead of using customer_name which is a column in invoices table. Basically we just get around the problem and do not know what causes the problem above. All rspec cases which failed pass again.